# Execute function from template

Tags: django, django-templates

How is it possible to run a function from a template?
I want to have a link that just calls a function.
I'm pretty new to django and not sure how to interact between a template and a view.

Answer (score 1):

The template should have a button, link, or AJAX request.

This request will go to your view, which will start the script.

**app/views.py**

```
def script(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'app/script.html')
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        # start script
        # and return something to show the user
```

**app/script.html**:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form method="POST">
            <input type="submit" value="Start script">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Change the `form` `action` if you want to go to a different view to start the script.

Or you can use a link, though links are usually used for things which do not change state or "do" anything.

Answer (score 0):

Templates can't directly call anything on the server. You need to have a link or a button that goes to a view, and the view calls your script (or you can just put the code for the script into your view.)